# Compare bigrams and trigrams from same text

Tags: python, list, nlp, nltk

I have 2 list of normalised bigrams and trigrams from same text.
What I need is a list of trigrams, first two words of which contains a bigram from the same text. For example `['spam eggs blabla']` should give a match with `[spam eggs]`. Any ideas?

Comment: Hey @Alex Nitikin, just to be clear: You have two lists, one of bigrams and one of trigrams. You're looking for a sublist of your trigram list such that every element also contains a bigram in your bigram list, correct?

Comment: @Peter Dolan Thanks for your reply. First two elements of trigram should contain exact match from bigrams.

Comment: Hey @AlexNikitin, no problem. Are the bigrams/trigrams strings, or lists themselves? Does a trigram look like `['Hello', 'there', 'sir']` or `['hello there sir']`?

Comment: I don't like the idea but a simple way to do it is to use BLEU if you're considering ngram similarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split your `trigrams` to select first 2 and also last two words (just in case you want to analyze. Then you may do comparisons and at high level you may try `String Fuzzy Matching` for `100%` match.  Preferred data structure I would say `List`. Make list of all above two list of lists having 2 words from `trigrams` and then perform matching operation. For example:

```
li = ['spam eggs blabla']
li[0].split()[0:2]
output >> ['spam', 'eggs']
```

Now you may want to convert to string

```
li1 = li[0].split()[0:2]
str1 = ' '.join(li1)
```

Now you do similarly for `bigrams` and try comparisons.

For reference `String Fuzzy Match` [Here](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy)

Comment: Thanks! Could you advise how can I split a list of trigrams to sublist of words?

Comment: @AlexNikitin added , I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [prefix tree (also known as trie)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

Here is an example run:

```
In [1]: import pygtrie

In [2]: pygtrie?

In [3]: trie = pygtrie.StringTrie()

In [4]: pygtrie.StringTrie?

In [5]: trie['/spam/egg'] = True

In [6]: trie['/foo/bar/baz'] = True

In [7]: trie.prefixes('/spam/egg/one')
Out[7]: <generator object Trie.prefixes at 0x7f18e91d9bf8>

In [8]: list(trie.prefixes('/spam/egg/one'))
Out[8]: [('/spam/egg', True)]

In [9]: list(trie.prefixes('/spam/egg/two'))
Out[9]: [('/spam/egg', True)]

In [10]: list(trie.prefixes('/spam/egg/three'))
Out[10]: [('/spam/egg', True)]

In [11]: list(trie.prefixes('/foo/bar/baz/python'))
Out[11]: [('/foo/bar/baz', True)]
```

Comment: should `/` be used as a separator to insert and while inserting a key_or_slice in the trie in place of a space.

Comment: You can use space as a separator